# A particular value isn't stored in localstorage within phonegap when I close the app... Other do..Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

I was trying the whole week to get this working and it still aint! I'm very sure it's not a big deal! I new to phonegap and jquery and I think I haven't implemented the script correctly.

So I have his feature in my app where I have 5 lifes and each time I press a button they decrease and they regenerate each after 6 seconds aslo if the app is closed!! (further I'll change the time and I'll remove the button, I'll set to remove a life each time the player loses a lvl and to don't start a lvl if lifes == 0 so thst's not a issue for now)

This script actiolly decreases the time when I pressed the remove life buton and the current time and if its more or equal than 6 seconds it adds lifes representing that gap.

I also have an web example wich works except the strange fact that the lives and the date values aren't updating in the localstorage and also in the div only if I click somewhere random on the page. (this script helped me somebody to make but he also doesn't know how to fix the bug)
https://student.sps-prosek.cz/~eisead11it/web/IS/Administrace/index.html

I need this script in my phonegap application.
And fter implementing it I saw another BIG problem: It doesn't work if I close the app and reopen it.

I also made today the whole day some steps on the mobile version to try and find the bug... 
I pulled on each step the fresh localstorage db from the device:

1) I cleared the localstorage and I entered the app, I killed some lives and they regenerated ok. 
2) I left the app with all the 5 lives active and I closed it
3) after 1 sec I reopened it and I saw that the data from localstorage was empty
4) When I press the remove live button the lifes decreases but NO DATA was stored in the localstorage!!! and no lifes are regenerating
5) If I wait 5*15 sec (the time in wich all the lives shoud have been regenerated while this, the current life state is 0 in the app and also in the localstorage) or if I minimise the app and maximize and I PRESS AGAIN the button, a date is stored in the localstorage, the current lives are set to 4 and the lives begin to regenerate normally untill they reach 5.

I don't know why the date isn't stored if I reenter the app and I press the button. That might be the issue.

Otherwise everything is working fine while thw first run of the app.

I tested it on my galaxy s2, on galaxys2 mini, on eclipse emulator and on ripple emlator and still the same effects on all.

A strange thing is that the lvl and the life values are stored 100% perfectly in the localsorage and when I reenter the app they are still there EXCEPT the date value wich after reentering the app is lost.

I really really dont know why is that? I thing the bug is because the date isn't saved correctly or it gets removed when I start again the app.

THIS IS THE MAGIC SCRIPT:

Just a small date validator...

```
Date.prototype.isValid = function(first_argument) {
    if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(this) !== "[object Date]" )
        return false;
    return !isNaN(this.getTime());
}
```

The main var declaration among retrieving variables from localStorage

```
var timeout = null;
var maxlife = 5;
if (undefined === localStorage.life) {
    localStorage.life = maxlife;
}
if (undefined === localStorage.date||localStorage.date!="") {
    localStorage.date = "";
    var date = null;
}else{
    var date = new Date(Number(localStorage.date));
    if(!date.isValid()){
        date = null;
    }
}
var timeoutTime = 5 * 60000;
var life = Number(localStorage.life);
```

Lose life, set date if none exist yet. Set a timeout too and subtract life (& write it into localstorage).

```
function loseLife() {
    if (null === date) {
        date = new Date();
        localStorage.date = date.getTime();
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){addLife()}, timeoutTime);
    }
    life--;
    localStorage.life = life;
    lives.innerHTML = life;
    console.log(life);
}
```

Add life, set date new date or reset the date completely. Set a timeout, if needed, and add a life (& write it into localstorage).

```
function addLife() {
    life++;
    localStorage.life = life;
    if (life < maxlife) {
        date = new Date();
    localStorage.date = date.getTime();
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){addLife()}, timeoutTime);
    } else {
        date = null;
    localStorage.date = "";
    }
    lives.innerHTML = life;
}
```

Here you may need to change the hooks for blur (window not visible) and focus (window visible once again). Blur just clear timeout so it don't mess with us.

```
window.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

This function check how many time it can subtract our time needed to get life from difference of now and the date we lost a life.

```
function tillNow(){
    if (life < maxlife&&date!=null) {
        var d = new Date();
        var diff = d - date;
        while (diff - timeoutTime > 0) {
            diff = diff - timeoutTime;
            if (life < maxlife) {
                life++;
                console.log("add");
            }else{
                date = null;
                localStorage.date = "";
                break;
            }
        }
        lives.innerHTML = life;
        localStorage.life = life;
        if (life < maxlife) {
            date = new Date((new Date()).getTime()-diff);
            localStorage.date = date.getTime();
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){addLife()}, timeoutTime-diff);
        }
    }
}
```

Focus just call tillNow()

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function () {
    tillNow();
});
```

Onload do the same as focus, but fills the div with a value initially...

```
window.onload=function(){
    var lives = document.getElementById("lives");
    lives.innerHTML = life;
    tillNow();
}
```

allright and this is my repo: https://bitbucket.org/alecstheone/whatsnap

and the js is stored in /platforms/android/assets/www/js/index.js (not in the first www folder)

Please if someone can take a look if might be my fulfilled dream as I stayed the whole week the whole day fixing it without resoult and as there is such a few support on the phonegap side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it after a week of pain.. 
there was a bug: in the second if in the main var declaration it should be something like this:

```
if (undefined === localStorage.date||localStorage.date=="")
```

And I also removed the blur and focus events and used the onDeviceReady event that is featured within phonegap for the first declaration and tillNow() call!